AppCheckCore 'GoogleUtilities/GULKeychainStorage.h' file not found in my objective-c project
I gets the error:

'GoogleUtilities/GULKeychainStorage.h' file not found
in file - Pods/AppCheckCore/GACAppCheckStorage.h

The error occurred when i installed a new pod in an old objective-c project.
I have tried deleting derived data, clean build, deleting workspace, pod deintegrate and install etc...
Below is my podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '10.0'
# Uncomment this line if you are using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target ‘PurposeColor’ do
    
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.7.0'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8.3'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'MobileVLCKit', '~>3.3.0'
    pod 'EMEmojiableBtn'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
    pod 'algorithmia', '~>0.1.1'
    
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    
    
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~>5.7.1'
    pod 'SwiftGifOrigin'
    pod 'MarqueeLabel'
    pod 'NXPlacePicker'
    pod 'SVPullToRefresh'
    
    pod 'MKDropdownMenu'
end

target ‘Share’ do
    
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.7.0'
    
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8.3'
    
    
    
    
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    #pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    
    
end


target 'PurposeColorTests' do
    
end

target 'PurposeColorUITests' do
    
end

